# Angular - How use 'as FormArray' in formArray.controls: AbstractControl[]

Tags: angular, forms, controls, lint, formarray

I have a function that returns the controls of a FormArray:

```
getFormFControls() {
    return this.form.get('opts') ? (<FormArray>this.formQuestions.get('opts')).controls : null;
}
```

But when running the Lint check, I get this error:

`Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.`

I tried many ways to solve this problem, but I can't find a solution when it's a FormArray.controls: AbstractControl[].

Can someone help me?

Tried to remove the  and add the 'as FormArray' at the end, but I get an error.

I need to solve this without putting comment to ignore lint in the line

Answer (score 1):

Your error is trying to tell you to change this:

```
(<FormArray>this.formQuestions.get('opts')).controls : null;
```

to this:

```
(this.formQuestions.get('opts') as FormArray).controls : null;
```

They are equivalent but the first has fallen out of use as it gets confused with JSX.